# link a different payment profile to google developer account

Tags: google-play, adsense, mobile-application

my issue is really complicated but i will try my best to explain it,
so i created a google play developer account and paid the 25 dollars but it suddenly asked me to verify my identity by uploading a government issued document of a country i don't belong to.
Turns out a long time ago i created an adsense account and payment profile in which for some reason or by mistake (I don't even remember) I selected the wrong country and that payment profile is now linked with my developer account now.
I tried closing my payment profile but it said you have active subscriptions or services, you need to close them first.
And that active service is my adsense account that i mentioned earlier.
I tried closing my adsense account but it said "Your payments are on hold (Even though i have $0 earnings) clear them first".
And on my adsense account I am also getting the same popup to verify my identity.

I have no idea what to do now i have paid the $25 fee and i can't publish any apps before clearing this issue.
I have created another payment profile with my actual country selected but i don't know how to link this correct payment profile to my developer account and unlink the old one.

there must be a way i could fix this mess...
please help me

Comment: Currently experiencing the same issue. I had created an adsense account a long time ago for an organisation. I am now just an individual developer and to publish apps it's asking me to confirm my org, which doesn't exist. I have a support ticket open with Google and will update here when it's resolved.

Answer (score 0):

You have one shot at setting a payment profile for your Play Developer account. If you somehow close/delete it, you cannot add/link a new payment profile. You have to sign up for a new developer account, pay $25 registration fee again if you intend to monetize from Play.

See the yellow box at this page:
https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/3092739?hl=en&pli=1

When you close/delete payment profile linked to your Play developer account, you also lose record of your transaction ID unless you kept the e-mail, without which you cannot transfer apps to another account.